# Get previous element after drop

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html5-draggable

Is parent element from which draggable element was removed somewhere stored?

I have tried to make work arounds on dragStart with either

```
dataTransfer.setData
```

or

```
dataTransfer.addElement
```

With setData the element gets converted to string
addElement exists only in firefox

For easier editing I'm adding jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up saving in dragstart event

```
var parentElement = e.target.parentElement;
e.dataTransfer.setData('ParentId', parentElement.id);
```

and then getting that parent in drop event by

```
var parentItem = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('ParentId'));
```